# Using ng-change in search box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Request :

```
 $scope.viewAccount = function(){
      var json = {

  "json": {
    "request": {
      "servicetype": "60",
      "functiontype": "1014",
           "data": {
        "shortname": $scope.model.selectShortName,
        "groupzname": $scope.model.selectGname,
        "city": $scope.model.selectCity,
        "state": $scope.model.selectState,
        "country": $scope.model.selectCountry,
        "groupzcode": $scope.model.selectGcode,
         "activationstatus": true,
        "details": false,
        "sortbasedon": $scope.groupzname,
        "orderby": "desc",
        "limit":10,
           }

    }
  }
};

              UserService.viewListAccount(json).then(function(response) {

  console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
                 if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')
                        {
                   $scope.tableData = response.json.response.data;
                  console.log($scope.tableData);
                        }
                  else{
                  alert(response.json.response.statusmessage);

                  }

            }); 
        };
```

The above function is to display all datas into table.I have a search box in groupzname,shortname and I used ng-change and called a new function changeviewAccount() removing offset in request. But the problem here I get is even if I enter one letter in searchbox, the function is getting called everytime. I am new to AngularjS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ng-change , you can use [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur),whhich tells AngularJS what to do when an input box loses focus.

```
  <input ng-blur="changeviewAccount()" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Title">
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Its helpful.